# Read files one by one and waiting them to finish for continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am converting about 3000 log files to MongoDB. I can successfuly cycle through a single file with no hick-ups, using regex matches. But I cannot wrap my head around how to cycle all files in the folder and waiting each file to be done to do the next one.

My first thought was to fire a function forEach item in an array, which I provided with all the file names. But of course it fires them all at once without waiting the previous one to be done and just makes a mess.

Could anyone help me on that ?
Thanks a lot !

Here is what I am using so far :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import lineReader from 'line-reader'
import { getAllFilesSync } from 'get-all-files'

mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/logger', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then((e) => console.log('Connected to DB'))

const allDates = []

for await (const filename of getAllFilesSync(`./logs/`)) {
  let [date] = filename.match(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/i)
  allDates.push(date)
}

allDates.forEach((date) => {
  logToDB(date)
})

const regex = /\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\.[0-9])?\]\s\s/

async function logToDB(date) {
  lineReader.eachLine(`./logs/${date}.log`, (line) => {
    if (regex.test(line)) {
      let [dayDate] = date.match(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/i)
      let [time] = line.match(/\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\.[0-9])?\]/)
      let [, username, message] = line.match(/([a-z0-9_]+):\s(.*)/)
      const Logger = mongoose.model('logs', MessagesSchema)
      new Logger({
        date: new Date(`${dayDate} ${time}`),
        username: username,
        message
      }).save()
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
    const readline = require('readline');
    
    async function processLineByLine( filename ) {
      const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    
      const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
      });
    
      for await (const line of rl) {
        // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
        //Do whatever you need to do with mongoDB here
        console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
      }
    }

    //Create a list of your file names;
    const files = [];

    files.forEach(file => {
        await processLineByLine(file);
    });
```

Comment: This works flawlessly ! Thanks a lot. I had to add a sleep function (100ms) I found online because it was just blazingly too fast for the DB to process. It is going to race through the 48 millions lines in a matter of minutes

Comment: Where are you using the sleep? Generally I would avoid using a hard set sleep like that in case the DB has a slow down of some sort. Probably better off awaiting the DB operation.

Comment: I added it at the end of the for await loop but you are right regardless, I simply added `await` in from of each `new Logger({ query }).save()` and it now works as intended